# Heroku Friendly_Id Gem undefined method slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, friendly-id

So Iv created a basic app on rails and uploaded it to heroku. Everything works perfectly on my local machine including the [friendly_Id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem.

Iv pushed my app to heroku and everything works fine, up until i try to post something where I get an error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `slug' for #<Post:0x007f6aedb2d248>):
```

All my models and relations are set up correctly as below:

**Post.rb**

```
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged
```

And I also ran a migration

```
  def change
    add_column :tutorials, :slug, :string
  end
```

Locally what I did my mistake was delete the migration file, but the column stayed in the `postgresql` database. So i deleted the column `slug` and created a new migration and added the column again and its all fine locally.

Now When I look at my db schema on my local machine it contains the slug column.

**db/schema.rb**

```
create_table "post", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "slug"
end
```

But when i check my db schema on heroku the column `slug` is not there. Iv even pushed all the changes up and when i run `heroku run rake db:migrate` I get an error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "slug" of relation "posts" does not exist
```

any help on how i can add this column to work on heroku?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?